# OpenShift - How to configure OpenShift server for credentials only, no public key required?

Tags: ssh, openshift, credentials

I recently made a OpenShift server, and I put in my public key during configuration.

I want to SSH using different computers, and I cannot find any place that allows me to use just basic username and password credentials instead.

Does anybody else know if and how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not connect to applications/gears on OpenShift Online using only username/password authentication.  If you would like to connect from multiple computers, you should generate an ssh key pair on each computer, and upload them to your OpenShift account through the web console, or you can run rhc setup on each computer and it will upload your key pair for you.